# AJAX HTTP POST Request not working all the time

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, post

I have a strange situation with an AJAX request I`m making from JavaScript.
The flow is like this:
On the click of a Submit button, the AJAX POST is triggered using

```
xmlhttp.open("POST",httpsPostURL,false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(queryString);
```

I used to be getting a response back which the same query string appended with some extra data.

Now, the problem is sometimes in the response , the extra info is not appended.
I`ve noticed the state change of the callback. The ready state is always 4 and status is 200.

I suspected caching issues and added a unique no in teh query string as follows:

```
       queryString = "CCNumber="+CCNumberVal+"&"+
                          "uniqueID="+Math.random();
```

Still doesn't explain why I`m not getting response in some machines in my network and only some times.

Comment: What is "the extra info" ? What is actually happening? What is shown in your browser js console? What is, in unambiguous terms, "the problem"?

Comment: u can use jquery for this i can show you how

Comment: @ddw147 if you're about to write an answer along the lines of "this is how to use `$.post` to do that with jquery" - you'll at least get a downvote from me. The question isn't tagged jQuery, it won't directly answer/address the (unclear) problem to show that.

Comment: @AD7six thats why i ask him , if he say yes then i will show him otherwise not

Comment: Let me reply to each comment..My HTTPS POST request contains a query String like "CCNUmber=1234123412341234". When the POST is successful, in the response a token is appended as follows "CCNUmber=1234123412341234&CCNumberTOken=123453242344234". The problem is that it is not working all the time.Though, I get a 200 response code, sometimes the response is the same query string that I sent without the appended data. On cleaning the cache and trying again, I get the expected result.So I`m not sure where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

see what happens here

you initialize  xmlhttp then send request to the server , it chage its state to 4

then again if you send request then xmlhttp state 4 will not cleared , so that change state event will not fire  as you wish

so i recommend use a function like

```
      ajaxpost(queystring ) { //code here }
```

so every time in that function  variable will initialize   for every call you will get your change state  event correctly , so as i do

Comment: I was wondering if using JQuery will make any difference..Even with JavaScript, we can monitor the state change,rt..My code is somewhat like below. Even, when I don't get the expected response, the control goes inside the  innermost if and tries to read the response.                                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
      var response =xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: you are updating any div/area in html after ajax ?

Comment: After I read the response,I update one of the hidden fields using the value obtained from the response.

Comment: http://simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/ and 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm
 see this links , i used this for my ajax purpose and i didnt get any cahce issue till date